# How to use a ssh github repo with spring cloud-server on cloud foundry

Tags: spring-cloud, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services, configserver

I'm trying to use Spring Cloud Services Config Server on Cloud Foundry backed by a github repository. I need to use ssh access because it's a private git repo but I keep getting the error

`UnknownHostKey: github.com. RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48`

To create the service I'm using:

`cf create-service -c '{"git": { "uri": "ssh://git@github.com/user/myrepo.git", "label": "master", "privateKey":"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n...\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "hostKey":"AAAA...FFAaQ==", "hostKeyAlgorithm": "ssh-rsa" } }' p-config-server standard config-server`

I'm getting the `hostKey` directly from my known_hosts file.

I've tried testing it on PCFDev and I get the more generic error message of `Unable to reach host.` Even though I can ssh to the app container and clone the repo myself.

I've been following these instructions http://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/1-4/common/config-server/configuring-with-git.html#ssh-repository-access.

What am I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should contact your PCF support contact.

Comment: This looks correct and the prefix/suffix of the `hostKey` value seems similar to what I have for github.com. I've been running this locally using Spring Cloud Services Config Server and successfully creating an instance. This is using Spring Cloud Services version 1.4.3. Please do contact Pivotal support so we can gather more information from you about the environment. Thank you.

Comment: Did you figure out why ? I am facing this same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring Cloud Services team have found a bug on at least 1.11.7+ and probably 1.11.x+ for SCS when using Git SSH configuration for Config Server. They're working on a patch.

So the answer, unfortunately, is to either downgrade or wait for the patch.

Comment: How do you know about this?